# Can't select element with multiple attributes using XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

trying to parse news.google

```html
<a target="_blank"class="article usg-AFQjCNFr5aujpYnTzdHNYfHZw_gNN6iq-w sig2-1esugE2Sy8Bhe2CzulGmsA did--5114870031117960448 esc-thumbnail-link" href="http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/trump-blasts-media-in-rally-celebrating-100-days-as-president/article34858356/" url="http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/trump-blasts-media-in-rally-celebrating-100-days-as-president/article34858356/" id="MAA4AEgAUABgAWoCY2E"  ssid="h" >
```

I want the url attribute. I can't get the url attribute. All I get us null reference.

XPath to find this multi attribute element:

```
HtmlNode aNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@target='_blank' and @class='article usg-AFQjCNFr5aujpYnTzdHNYfHZw_gNN6iq-w sig2-1esugE2Sy8Bhe2CzulGmsA did--5114870031117960448 esc-thumbnail-link' and @href='http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/trump-blasts-media-in-rally-celebrating-100-days-as-president/article34858356/' and @url='http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/trump-blasts-media-in-rally-celebrating-100-days-as-president/article34858356/' and @id='MAA4AEgAUABgAWoCY2E' and @ssid='h']");
```

I get a null reference just trying to find this element.
The attribute values like the url and href are always changing. Is there a way to get the url based on the attributes in the element and not on the attribute value? Something like if an element has these five attributes then select the value for url? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to select an element by the *presence* of attributes, rather than specific attribute *values*:

Test HTML:

```
var html = @"
<!-- match -->
<a target='_blank'class='article usg-AFQjCNFr5aujpYnTzdHNYfHZw_gNN6iq-w sig2-1esugE2Sy8Bhe2CzulGmsA did--5114870031117960448 esc-thumbnail-link' href='http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/trump-blasts-media-in-rally-celebrating-100-days-as-president/article34858356/' url='http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/trump-blasts-media-in-rally-celebrating-100-days-as-president/article34858356/' id='MAA4AEgAUABgAWoCY2E'  ssid='h' ></a>
<!-- NO match, missing url -->
<a target='_blank' href='NO MATCH'' ssid='' id='' class=''></a>
<!-- match -->
<a target='_blank' href='#' ssid='' id='' class='' url='MATCH'><a/>
<!-- NO match, missing multiple wanted attributes -->
<a target='_blank' href='#' url='NO MATCH'></a>
";
```

and a little LINQ:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
var wantedLinks = from a in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")
    where a.Attributes["url"] != null
    && a.Attributes["ssid"] != null
    && a.Attributes["href"] != null
    && a.Attributes["id"] != null
    && a.Attributes["class"] != null
    && a.Attributes["target"] != null
    select a;

foreach (var a in wantedLinks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.Attributes["url"].Value);
}
```

Output - notice links missing all six attributes are skipped:

```
http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/trump-blasts-media-in-rally-celebrating-100-days-as-president/article34858356/
MATCH
```